# Statsmodels Dynamic Factor model prediction

Tags: python, time-series, statsmodels, forecasting

```
         CDS        KKHA            TicariTL    TOPLAM  TüketiciTP  Ticari      Elektrik    GDP
2022Q1  -1.020047   4.082617    2.309897    2.484563    1.480060    -0.427367   0.221842    7.6
2022Q2  2.309111    3.949957    3.540231    3.107952    2.305203    -1.087359   0.231423    7.8
2022Q3  6.706186    3.118210    4.236057    3.460666    2.541820    -1.682365   -0.049016   4.0
2022Q4  8.919830    4.827395    4.578350    2.831477    3.208416    -1.419733   -0.773304   3.5
2023Q1  3.514298    3.725145    3.937879    2.454835    3.606279    -1.493838   -0.654923   NaN
```

I have the dataframe above. As it can be seen `"GDP"` for the first quarter is not announced yet and my aim is to "nowcast" it using other variables on the dataframe like `"CDS"`, `"KKHA"` and more. However, when I used `DynamicFactor`:

```
mod = sm.tsa.DynamicFactor(çeyreklik.drop(columns=['İTH','REELKUR','BRENT','SYHTGLR','ÜRHA','KRF']),k_factors=1, factor_order=1, error_order=1,error_var=False,enforce_stationarity=False).fit(separate_params=False)

results=mod.get_prediction(start='2016',end='2024')
tahminler=results.predicted_mean['GDP'].resample('Q').last()
```

It does not nowcast the 2023Q1 GDP growth using independent variables of 2023Q1. It does predict 2023Q1 GDP using 2022Q4 data therefore it has a lag.

For example my prediction output is the following:

```
2016Q3     4.044086
2016Q4     1.595537
2017Q1     2.532617
```

But actually 2016Q4 `1.59` does belong to 2016Q3 and 2017Q1 `2.53` corresponds to 2016Q4.
How can I solve this issue? I want to nowcast 2023 Q1 GDP, which is `NaN` on the dataframe above, using other variables on the same line, 2023 Q1.